# showing and hiding layouts from Toolbar in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, menu, xamarin, show-hide, toolbar

The xml shows the toolbar design I've been working on in Xamarin.

```
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <item android:id="@+id/action_searchAdv"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
  <item android:id="@+id/action_searchMore"
        android:title="Advance Search"
        android:icon ="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float"
        app:showAsAction ="always"/>
   </menu>
```

And This is the app design axml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_advSearch"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/layout_AdvSearch"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spBloodGroup" />
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spClubGroup" />
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spSexGroup" />
</LinearLayout>
<Button
    android:text="Sync"
    android:id="@+id/btnSync"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<ListView
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="#AAAAAAAA"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"
    android:listSelector="#aa33b5e5"
    android:background="#222222"
    android:id="@+id/listContacts" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

The group/Club/Gender dropdowns are in a Linear layout "layout_AdvSearch".
I want to be able to show and hide this layout from my toolbar menu item (carot).
Task seem to be pretty simple but not able to figure it out. 
Any suggestions on how would I make it show/hide ? Also same item on item click
how can I change the carot icon from down to up [toggle]?

```
        public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        if (item.ItemId == Android.Resource.Id.Home)
            Finish();
        if (item.TitleFormatted.ToString() == "Advance Search")
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Top ActionBar pressed: " +            item.ItemId.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
            //Toggle the layout view
        }
        return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find any reference of **carot** in your code. Assuming that your linearLayout's id inside ToolBar is carot, you can use the following code snippet:

```
mainLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: That doesnt seem to work, this is how I'm referencing to the linear layout.
[`
private LinearLayout _layoutAdvSearch;
_layoutAdvSearch = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.layout_AdvSearch);

_layoutAdvSearch.Visibility(false); // doesn't work 
_layoutAdvSearch.setVisible() ;// no such method for layout
`]

Comment: Thanks man, did a bit research and found  your's works for Java and hence found it's Xamarin equivalent code,  <br/>
`_layoutAdvSearch.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;`  <br/>
worked fine now